# Detect $ in an email with a current regex expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to modify a script which uses regex to check whether given email is valid or not. Its working fine but failed to validate email like "foo$!@bar.com".

Here is the regex :-

`` var tester = /^[-!#$%&'*+\/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z{|}~](\.?[-!#$%&'*+\/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z`{|}~])*@[a-zA-Z0-9](-?\.?[a-zA-Z0-9])*\.[a-zA-Z](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])+$/; ``

Can anyone help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: search a little more, you will find answer..
You can use `validator.js` an _npm_ package to validate or you can use `regex101` (google it) to verify your regex against test cases

Comment: As per W3C guidelines $ is vaild in personal part. https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php

Comment: Why are you trying to validate an email address accepting characters that are not valid to an email address? Have you tried escaping special characters?

Comment: Actually its a function in my code. I think i need to replace it all with a library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate an email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: @Bjorn I don't think those examples will match emails containing special characters

Comment: @DNKROZ you are right. sorry. should have looked better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/gvucy3/1